# Retrieve current class type during compile time in C++

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to create a C++ macro that - if called within the method of a class - accepts a `void*` value and casts it into the current class type?

```
class Foo{
  void bar();
  void baz(){ void* pInst = some_magic_source(); SOME_MACRO(pInst)->bar(); }
};
```

The solution should work with VC++ 2012+ and GCC 4.8+.

(I need this as a part of a more complex macro)

Comment: Use inheritance for this and let `some_magic_source` return a pointer to a common base class. Stop using `void*` and stop using macro's.

Comment: @rubenvb `some_magic_source()` is part of a C-compatible library and can therefore not return any class types. I really need to work with `void*` values

Comment: so you're telling me you're using a C interface to a C++ library (because you're calling a member function on the casted object)? Can't you just use the... C++ library?

Comment: Also, how can a library function return an opaque pointer to a class type you're defining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer to the current class type is the type of `this`, leading to the following simple macro:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(x) (static_cast<decltype(this)>(x))
```

Be aware that the current class type may be cv-qualified (and thus, the `this` pointer may point to a cv-qualified type, meaning that the cast may result in a pointer to a cv-qualified object). You can easily use type traits like [`remove_cv`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_cv/) to deal with this if so desired.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why this would ever have to be a macro.

Comment: I think the OP expected a more complicated solution ;)

Comment: @rubenvb There actually is. And I find it quite sad that there is no __CLASS__ macro to put in the current class at compile-time. This is absolutely needed for macros that use Class member function pointers for example. Right now you always have to pass the class into the macro instead of the macro being able to get that by itself.